# percentage bins based on predefined buckets

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a series of numbers and I would like to know % of numbers falling in every bucket of a dataframe.

`df['cuts']` have 10, 20 and 50 as values.  Specifically, I would like to what % of `series` are in `[0-10], (10-20] and (20-50]` bin and this should be appended to the `df` dataframe.

I wrote the following code.  I definitely feel that it could be improvised.  Any help is appreciated.

```
bin_cuts = [-1] + list(df['cuts'].values)
out = pd.cut(series, bins = bin_cuts)
df_pct_bins = pd.value_counts(out, normalize= True).reset_index()
df_pct_bins = pd.concat([df_pct_bins['index'].str.split(', ', expand = True), df_pct_bins['cuts']], axis = 1)
df_pct_bins[1] = df_pct_bins[1].str[:-1].astype(str)
df['cuts'] = df['cuts'].astype(str)
df_pct_bins = pd.merge(df, df_pct_bins, left_on= 'cuts', right_on= 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sample data `df` and `s`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(cuts=[10, 20, 50]))
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(50, size=1000))
```

---

**Option 1**
`np.searchsorted`

```
c = df.cuts.values
df.assign(
    pct=df.cuts.map(
        pd.value_counts(
            c[np.searchsorted(c, s)],
            normalize=True
        )))

   cuts    pct
0    10  0.216
1    20  0.206
2    50  0.578
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.cut`

```
c = df.cuts.values
df.assign(
    pct=df.cuts.map(
        pd.cut(
            s,
            np.append(-np.inf, c),
            labels=c
        ).value_counts(normalize=True)
    ))

   cuts    pct
0    10  0.216
1    20  0.206
2    50  0.578
```